# Chapter 65: Headband logo not consistent (he usually has a "sound village" symbol)

Tags: naruto

So I am starting to read Naruto and I find that there are lots of characters. To keep track I look at their headbands and I noticed something in chapter 65. Marked in photo, is this a mistake or on purpose? Cause it isn't consistent with previous few pages. If anyone knows please let me know...[image: chapter65]

Comment: Could you [edit] and clarify by "*it isn't consistent with previous few pages*"?

Comment: he has a "sound village" symbol. and suddenly in this picture, he has the "konoha" one.

Comment: Ah, I see. According to [Fandom Wikia](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Life_and_Death_Battles!!), looks like it was indeed a mistake.

Comment: lol, they are trying to use substitution Jutsu but :D they are worst than naruto... only able to copy headband...